# find and count repeated occurances within a list - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is a challange

looking for a one liner solution:

assume we have a list:

```
a = [1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1]
```

idea is to get dynamic solution to find number of -1 within a list, but from the end to the start AND stop counting it when first value (from end to start) is 1.

In this case solution should be 3.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing site. Post what you have tried so far.

Comment: when you find first occurence of 1. But from back to the start ofcourse.

Comment: only -1 and 1 that's it

Comment: What have you come up with?

Comment: was just think about this problem and i found it interesting

Comment: have a look at [codegolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is

```
    a[::-1].index(1) if 1 in a else len(a)
```

`a[::-1]` reverses the list.

`index(1)` finds the first occurrence of 1 in the reversed list

Since you mentioned there's only `1`'s and `-1`'s this is sufficient for finding the number of `-1`'s before the `1` at the end.

Since `index(1)` throws an error if there's no `1`'s in the list, the `if 1 in a else len(a)` conditional handles that by returning the length of the list.